# How can PBKDF2 using HMAC SHA-1 return more than 20 bytes?

Tags: cryptography, sha1, hmac, pbkdf2

If Node's `crypto.PBKDF2` uses HMAC SHA-1, how can the key length ever be more than 20 bytes?

Here's what I understand (apparently incorrectly): `crypto.PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, callback)` uses HMAC SHA-1 to hash a password with a salt. Then it takes that hash and hashes *it* with the same salt. It repeats that for however many iterations you tell it and then passes you back the result. The result is truncated to the number of bytes you specified in `keylen`.

[SHA-1 outputs 160 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Comparison_of_SHA-functions), or 20 bytes. However, I can ask for `keylen` more than 20 bytes from `crypto.PBKDF2`, and past the 20th byte, the data doesn't repeat. That doesn't make sense to me.

**What am I misunderstanding here?**

Try it out:

```
c.pbkdf2('password', 'salt', 1, 21, function(err, key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
        console.log(key[i].toString(36));
    }
});
```

I would expect to see some kind of pattern after the 20th byte, but I don't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To derive the `i`th block, PBKDF2 runs the full key derivation, with `i` concatenated to the salt. So to get your 21st byte, it simply runs the derivation again, with a different effective salt, resulting in completely different output. This means deriving 21 bytes is twice as expensive as deriving 20 bytes.

---

I recommend against using PBKDF2 to derive more than the natural output size/size of the underlying hash. Often this only slows down the defender, and not the attacker.

I'd rather run `PBKDF2` once to derive a single master key, and then use HKDF to derive multiple secrets from it. See [How to salt PBKDF2, when generating both an AES key and a HMAC key for Encrypt then MAC? on crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5976/how-to-salt-pbkdf2-when-generating-both-an-aes-key-and-a-hmac-key-for-encrypt-t)

Comment: Interesting post, currently implementing HKDF for Bouncy :)

Comment: Note that I fully agree with your assessment on using PBKDF2 regarding larger output sizes. Personally I think this is reason enough to think about creating a PBKDF3 or something similar to create longer OKM (output keying material) for PBE constructs. KDF's suffer from very little attention in the crypto world. Personally I had already coupled KDF2 with PBKDF2, but as HKDF is safer, that one is certainly preferred. David has accepted my implementation in the mean while :)

Comment: @owlstead Related mailing list: [crypt-dev](http://www.openwall.com/lists/crypt-dev)

Comment: I was thinking that NIST probably should focus a bit more on KDF's, they do seem to have quite a bit of knowledge on them already, that or more advanced signature schemes